# Windows Form Application Button doesent work

Tags: c++, windows, winforms

I've made a new Windows Form Application , and I tried to make a button to multiply two numbers but the button doesent work...This is 
 MyForm.cpp

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

Project5::MyForm form;
Application::Run(%form);
}
```

MyForm.h

```
#pragma once

 namespace Project5 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for MyForm
/// </summary>
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~MyForm()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox3;
protected:

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

 #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(148, 169);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->button1->Text = L"button1";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(35, 27);
        this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
        this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
        this->textBox1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->textBox1->Text = L"1";
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(35, 65);
        this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
        this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
        this->textBox2->TabIndex = 2;
        this->textBox2->Text = L"2";
        // 
        // textBox3
        // 
        this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(35, 109);
        this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
        this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
        this->textBox3->TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // MyForm
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(282, 253);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Name = L"MyForm";
        this->Text = L"MyForm";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
 #pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    int a, b, c;
    a = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox1->Text);
    b = System::Convert::ToInt16(textBox2->Text);
    c = b + a;
    textBox3->Text = System::Convert::ToString(c);
    }
};
```

}

The Application start but when I press the button nothing happened
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you please post the designer's source code?

Comment: Aside from the fact your code adds the numbers rather than multiplying, have you tried debugging to make sure that the text in `textBox1` and `textBox2` is being converted to integers correctly. (I's also convert to Int32 rather than Int16.

Comment: The button doesent respond to any command..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button designer code doesn't have this line:

```
this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
```

If you double click on the button in the visual designer it should add this for you. If it hasn't just add this line and the button handler should be hooked up correctly.